# popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover two different types of popovers

Tags: swift, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I am wondering if anyone knows a better way to achieve the following. I have a two different types of popovers. The first(popover type 1) should be able to be dismissed by touching outside of popover. The second(popover type 2) needs to have the touch outside popover dismiss disabled. I kinda figured it with the included code.

What I wanted to know, is there a less "hacky" way of doing this.

```
 func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {

    var returnBool:Bool!
    if popoverPresentationController.sourceView .isKindOfClass(myCustomClass) {
        println("popover type 1")
        returnBool = true
    } else {
        println("popover type 2")
        returnBool = false
    }

    return returnBool
}
```

Comment: What about that solution feels "hacky"? `popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover()` is designed to decide whether to dismiss popover from user interaction. Maybe conditions could be improved, but it would require more info that you provided

Comment: Try to use objc_setassociatedobject and objc_associatedobject). I think it will be much more clearer to understand. But you in any case need to use popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover method.

Comment: Thanks for the help Vasy & Jakubl, Ill do some reading up :) I mean the solution I have works. Might mark this as a come back and clean up later type thing :) Once again thanks guys.